# How to import dependency into Vuex actions?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex

What is the correct way to import functions into Vuex actions? I ask because I get the following eslint error when trying to import a [Firebase `doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) into my action code:

```
'doc' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
'doc' is defined but never used.eslintno-unused-vars
(alias) function doc(firestore: FirebaseFirestore, path: string, ...pathSegments: string[]): DocumentReference<DocumentData> (+2 overloads)
import doc
```

Here's the `actions.js` code:

```js
import { doc } from "firebase/firestore"
import {db} from '~/plugins/firebase.js'

export default {

async getUserProfile({ commit }, authUser) {
  try {
    const docRef = doc(db, 'users', authUser.uid) // <----trying to use `doc()` here but get that eslint error
    ....
   }
....
}
```

Why can't I import the `doc()` function into the `getUserProfile()` action?

Updated with screenshot:

[image: eslint error]

Comment: There is probably something else here. Does it exist in `firestore`? No code between the one you showed us?

Comment: I have a component that uses the same import statement without any issues. It's just that when I try `import {doc} from 'firebased/firestore'` in my `actions.js` file, I get that eslint error. Updated with screenshot above.

Comment: Ok i think i got it...i had another line like so: `const doc = await docRef.get()` and that was causing issues thinking that I was redefining `doc` import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this was caused by the fact that `doc` was (re)declared later in the code, [as noted by the OP in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68408282/how-to-import-dependency-into-vuex-actions/68422058#comment120918798_68408282). Hence why ESlint was complaining about unused variable.